How to check if a table is empty in dbt?
Tried below 2 methods to check if a table is empty. Have to run if part or else part based on whether a table is empty or not
Method 1: Tried this and below prints a even if table XYZ has rows in it (expected: abcd)
`{% set row_count_query %}
select count(*) from {{ source('dbt', 'XYZ') }}
{% endset %}

{% set results = run_query(
    row_count_query
) %}
{% if execute %}
    {% if results | int == 0 %} a
    {% else %} abcd
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
`

Method 2: Below prints F even if table is empty (expected : E)
`{%- call statement(
    "my_statement",
    fetch_result=True
) -%}
    select count(*)
    from
        {{
            source(
                "dbt",
                "XYZ",
            )
        }}
{%- endcall -%}

{%- set op = load_result(
    "my_statement"
) %}
{%- set op_data = op["data"] %}

{% print(op_data) %}

{% if op_data == "[(0,)]" %} "E"
{% else %} "F"
{%- endif %}
`


This works
{% if execute %}
    {%- set table_rows = run_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM XYZ") -%}
{% else %}
    {%- set table_rows = [] -%}
{% endif %}

{% if table_rows[0][0] == 0 %}
   
    SELECT 'Table XYZ is empty' AS status;
{% else %}
  
    SELECT 'Table XYZ is not empty' AS status;
{% endif %}

